# jstl access a second array value with foreach index

Tags: jstl

i have two arrays (strings delimited with commas) and i made a foreach loop on one of this vars
i need to be able to access to the other string with the foreach index like

```
<c:set var="name" value="Zara,nuha,roshy" />
<c:set var="name2" value="Zara2,nuha2,roshy2" />
<c:forEach items="${name}" delims="," var="name" varstatus="i">
       <c:out value="${name}"/><br>
    </c:forEach>
```

i need to access name2 values, in the name foreach, is it possible without doing another foeach?

Comment: What do you mean by "access name2 values"? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: No is not possible. It's like asking *can I traverse an array without using a `for` loop?*

Comment: well actually you can do this in javascript, dont know if you got the question what i mean is if using 1 foreach you can access another array value, that`s my question.

Comment: You could if you had actual arrays, because you could access their elements by index. What you have is two strings, that each have to be parsed and transformed to arrays.

Comment: right, well thats the problem, just can use jstl

Comment: Delimited strings are not arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The varstatus variable you are using contains a value "index" that you can use.
But, you can't operate on a string like that (not that I know of at least).
First, you need to convert name2 to a proper array or list. Then you can access it inside the for loop:

```
${name2list[i.index]}
```

Now, how to convert it to an array? How about the split function?

```
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<c:set var="name2list" value="${fn:split(name2, ',')}"/>
```

Comment: well actually thank you, this worked fine, just that i had to use a fortokens instead of a foreach, thanks so much :D

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, contrary to some previous comments.

See the following example based on the question:

```
<c:set var="names" value="Zara,nuha,roshy" />
<c:set var="names2" value="Zara2,nuha2,roshy2" />
<c:forEach items="${names.split(',')}" varStatus="i" var="name" >
    ${name} : ${names2.split(',')[i.index]}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

Essentially we're using a string split function with expression language to get a string array from list comma separated values. Within the loop we the get the second value from the names2 array by using the varStatus index. I believe this accomplishes the task.

Comment: i`ll check it tomorrow and tell you how it worked for me, thanks

Comment: Will probably work as well as my version. And if the lists are short, it's not a problem. But the split occurs many times. Not that big a deal unless there is thousands of items in the lists (wild guess).

Comment: Yep. Though I think I would reference an array or list directly rather than a comma separated string, personally.

Comment: actually this one didn`t work, maybe cause i used it in a foreach instead of a fortokens, but well, thanks anyway